# Bash shell to make RANGE from list of IP addresses

Tags: bash, shell, ip, range

I need `bash` code to generate a RANGE of given IP addresses.
For example if I have the following simple list:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.5
1.1.2.1
1.2.3.4
100.100.1.2
100.100.1.3
```

My output will be:

```
(1.1.1.1-1.1.1.3) 
1.1.1.5 
1.1.2.1 
1.2.3.4 
(100.100.1.2-100.100.1.3)
```

...and so on.

ONLY nearest IPS will included in RANGE.

Comment: If you'd like it for bash, you should probably tag it. Also, why makefile? Use `{}` in the editor to markup data - and the code you've tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While it is certainly possible to write this in bash, covering all the corner cases is quite hard.  Can you install a special-purpose tool for this task, like `iprange`?

`iprange -j` output is very close to what you need, and you can eliminate the singleton ranges like this:

```
iprange -j | sed 's/^\(.*\)-\1$/\1/'
```

Comment: thank you for answer, no, I cannot install external tools

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution inside GNUmake, using [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt), a library for general purpose programming in GNUmake.

```
include gmtt-master/gmtt-master/gmtt.mk

ip-inc = $(strip $(call -ip-inc,$(word 1,$(subst ., ,$1)),$(word 2,$(subst ., ,$1)),$(word 3,$(subst ., ,$1)),$(word 4,$(subst ., ,$1))))
-ip-inc = $(if $(findstring :$4:,:255:),$(if $(findstring :$3:,:255:),$(if $(findstring :$2:,:255:),$(if $(findstring :$1:,:255:),0.0.0.0,$(call decimal-inc,$1).0.0.1),$1.$(call decimal-inc,$2).0.1),$1.$2.$(call decimal-inc,$3).1),$1.$2.$3.$(call decimal-inc,$4))

until-neq = $(if $(call str-eq,$(word 2,$1),$(call ip-inc,$2)),$(call until-neq,$(wordlist 2,2147483647,$1),$(call ip-inc,$2)),$2$(rparen) $(call gen-ip-range,$(wordlist 2,2147483647,$1)))

gen-ip-range = $(if $1,$(if $(call str-eq,$(call ip-inc,$(firstword $1)),$(word 2,$1)),$(lparen)$(firstword $1)-$(call until-neq,$1,$(firstword $1)),$(firstword $1) $(call gen-ip-range,$(wordlist 2,2147483647,$1))))


IP_LIST =   1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2 1.1.1.3 1.1.1.5 1.1.1.255 1.1.2.1 1.2.3.4   1.255.255.255 100.100.1.2 100.100.1.3 

IP_RANGES := $(call gen-ip-range,$(IP_LIST))
$(info $(IP_RANGES))
```

Effectively it is a functional program which converts a sorted list of IP addresses to your range format. Funny IP addresses with leading 0's or unsorted lists are not handled in this simple example (but could be with gmtt onboard functions).